# position radio input outside list marker

Tags: html, css, forms, html-lists

Is there a neat way of styling the following:

```
<ol>
   <li>How many licks to get to the center?
    <ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
        <li><input id="q1a" type="radio" name="q1" value="1" />
            <label for="q1a">One</label></li>
        <li><input id="q1b" type="radio" name="q1" value="2" />
            <label for="q1b">Two-hoo</label></li>
        <li><input id="q1c" type="radio" name="q1" value="3" />
            <label for="q1c">Three</label></li>
    </ol>
   </li>
</ol>
```

So that the answers in the nested `ol` output with the radio bubble to the left of the marker?

```
() a. One
() b. Two-hoo
() c. Three
```

So far all of the answers I've seen either require cheating (helper markup), are from 5 years ago, or require positioning the inputs with `position: absolute` which I wouldn't be opposed to if I knew they would reliably line up to the marker and not potentially look like crap depending on the length of the item.

Is this addressed directly or indirectly with css3 or html5?

Comment: Is the first input supposed to be outside of the list item?

Comment: noooo. fixed. thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/C6u4c/ Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @Itay - Maybe, but I'd prefer to not use non-relative units and I can't seem to get it to work with ems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very cool way is to use CSS calculations.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/C6u4c/2/)

```
.letters-counter {
    counter-reset: my-counter;
}
.letters-counter li label:before {
    content: counter(my-counter, lower-alpha) ".";
    counter-increment: my-counter;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

For further reading:

- [Using CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters)
- [Can I use CSS counters?](http://caniuse.com/css-counters) (The answer is yes)
- [Numbering in style](http://css-tricks.com/numbering-in-style/)

Comment: That is really cool albeit probably under supported in some archaic browsers / systems. Just speculating though, I think it's an awesome solution!

Comment: I will take it! It's not my ideal choice, as it isn't as "native" as I'd like (for example, no other marker-related style rules could be applied outside of this rule), but it's nice and seamless and bonus points for the marker being part of the label.

Answer (score 1):

I believe using `position:absolute` should work and wouldn't depend on the length of the item, take this CSS for example:

```
ol li ol{
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style-position: inside; 
}

ol li ol li{
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 2em; 
}

ol li ol li input[type="radio"]{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; 
}
```

The only thing is that you may need to tweak the padding to create the space between the input and the label.

Here's a **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/QSA5N/1/)**

Comment: +1 for the right way to apply position rules to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do a little cheating but not much.

```
<ol>
    <li>How many licks does it take to get to the center?
        <ol class="answerList">
            <li><input type="radio" id="q1a" name="q1" value="1" /><span>a.</span><label for="q1a">One</label></li>
            <li><input type="radio" id="q1b" name="q1" value="2" /><span>b.</span><label for="q1b">Two-hoo</label></li>
            <li><input type="radio" id="q1c" name="q1" value="3" /><span>c.</span><label for="q1c">Three</label></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

And then style it...

```
<style>
    .answerList{list-style-type:none;}
    .answerList span{font-weight:bold;}
</style>
```

Comment: Or just put the letter as part of the label :/ that way when it's clicked it will register with the radio button.

Comment: Afraid part of the goal is to not have defined labels but to use the `ol` marker. Otherwise I would just use `ul`

Comment: Yeah I understand. Perhaps if the css dependent version doesn't work the way you want all of the time it could be pretty easy to doctor this whole thing up in a nice json array and print it out with a simple function call. I'd do that or perhaps use a server side language to pull it off.